# what is range in nsstring and how we pass values in it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

What is range in `NSString`? example when we use the following function-

```
replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:
```

what should be passed in parameters?

scenario- find "aaa" in first half of a string and replace it with "bbb"

Comment: considered searching for description on developer.apple.com???? Try http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html

Comment: [ReplaceOccurrencesOfStrin](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ReplaceOccurrencesOfString)
and also
[NSRange](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSRange)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range parameter is of type `NSRange` which consists of `location` and `length`. As the name implies it specifies the range of characters in the string that should be used in the method.

Caveat: "Character" in this sense is really a Unicode UTF-16 "code fragment"—which is not what people commonly expect a character to be. So splitting a string in half could split in the middle of a surrogate pair, which renders the substrings invalid. To split at proper positions use `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:`.

Here's a proper example:

```
NSMutableString *myString = [@"有人给我们树立了炸弹" mutableCopy];
NSRange range = {0, [myString length] / 2};
range = [myString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:range];
[myString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"炸弹"
                          withString:@""
                             options:0
                               range:range];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *foo = @"ABCD 1234 ABCD TEST";
NSLog(@"Actual string: %@",foo);
int location = [foo rangeOfString:@"1234"].location; //location of 1234
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(location, (foo.length)-location); //create range
foo = [foo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ABCD" withString:@"foo" options:NSLiteralSearch range:range]; //replacing ABCD with foo
NSLog(@"Updated string: %@",foo);
```

> Actual string: ABCD 1234 ABCD TEST
>
> Updated string: ABCD 1234 foo TEST

**Here I'm searching 1234 within foo, then making NSRange for replacing occurance of ABCD after 1234 string**.